# Changing hours to days

Tags: php, mysql, time

**Editing the question.**

I have SQL like this:

```
`table1`.`DateField` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL {$days} DAY
```

Now 24 hours make a whole day. However, what if I want to do the query for the last 3 hours or so?

My `table1`.`DateField` is in the format of `2010-03-10 10:05:50`.

---

**Original post:**

If I have this

1 hour
2 hours
3 hours
..
24 hours

How would I change it to days?

Thanks.

Comment: Not all days have 24 hours (depending on what you mean by hours), I mean not all days have 24*60 minutes. Tell us more precisely what you want to do.

Comment: Divide by 24? Your question is too vague.

Comment: You can't. It's all in one day, so you can't have *days*. Unless you just divide by 24...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL not only knows `DAY` as a unit for an interval but also `HOUR`, `MINUTE`, ....
see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add

```
$x = 32;
$sql = "SELECT
   x,y,z
 FROM
   foo
 WHERE
   `table1`.`DateField` >= NOW() - INTERVAL $x HOUR
";
```

Answer (score 6):

```
$hours = 80;
$hid = 24; // Hours in a day - could be 24, 8, etc
$days = round($hours/$hid);

if( $days < 0 )
{
        echo "$hours hours";
}
else
{
        echo "$days days";
}
```

This assumes you want the hours if it's less than 1 day. If not just remove the switch.

Answer (score 1):

As simple as:

- if you want to convert the total of those hour to day:
  Just sum the total of hours and that total must be divided by 24

  (1 + 2 + 3 + 5) / 24
- If you want to convert all of those hours to days:
  Just divide by 24 every hours in your list

  (1/24) (2/24) (3/24) (5/24)